# Winsock recebimento de informação pelo servidor

Tags: c#

Estou tentando enviar uma informação realmente grande ao servidor(11000), e o problema que tenho, é que ela não está chegando completa.

Vejam o código:

No servidor, há um loop.

```
    do
    {

        Tick = Environment.TickCount;

        Listen.AcceptClient();
        Listen.Update();
    }
```

Listen.update

```
public static void UpdateClient(UserConnection client)
{
    string data = null;
        byte[] buffer = new byte[Convert.ToInt32(client.TCPClient.Available)];
        try
        {
            client.TCPClient.GetStream().Read(buffer, 0, Convert.ToInt32(client.TCPClient.Available));
        }
        catch
        {
            int code = System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.GetExceptionCode();
            Console.WriteLine("Erro Num: " + code);
        }
        data = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer);
        Console.WriteLine("Data is: " + data);
        Console.WriteLine("Size is: " + data.Length);
        Server.Network.ReceiveData.SelectPacket(client.Index, data);
        client.TCPClient.GetStream().Flush();
}
```

Listen.AcceptClient

```
    if (listener.Pending())
    {
        //Adicionamos ele na lista
        Clients.Add(new UserConnection(listener.AcceptTcpClient(), Clients.Count()));
```

E isso é o winsock server.

Alguém tem alguma dica ou solução?

Comment: Seria problema com ToInt32? Acredito que TCPClient.Available já retorna Int32

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Listen.Update

Ocorre que a função `Read` que faz a leitura em streams não garante a leitura de todos os dados enviados de uma única vez. Isso acontece para melhorar a performance em streams. Conforme os pacotes de dados vão chegando ao cliente, eles vão sendo disponibilizados para leitura.

Quando você chama a função `Read` ela só retorna de forma imediata se já houver chegado algum pacote de dados ao cliente através da conexão, senão ela entra em modo de espera e aguarda a chegada de algum pacote. Essa rotina pode levar várias rodadas.

A função `Read` fará a leitura dos dados disponíveis até um determinado comprimento (comprimento de buffer, 1024 neste caso) e retorna a quantidade de bytes lidos. Caso não haja dados disponíveis para leitura, a função `Read` entrará em modo de espera até que atinja o tempo definido em `ReadTimout` ou chegue algum pacote. Caso `ReadTimout` seja atingido, uma exceção será lançada. E se a stream ou a conexão for encerrada, a função `Read` retornará 0 (zero), indicando que não há mais dados a serem lidos.

Portanto, será necessário encerrar a stream ou a conexão para indicar que os dados foram completamente enviados.

```
public static void UpdateClient(UserConnection client) {
    System.IO.MemoryStream mStream = new System.IO.MemoryStream(client.TCPClient.Available);
    System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream nStream = client.TCPClient.GetStream();

    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    try {
        while(true) {
            int nBytes = nStream.Read(buffer, 0, 1024);
            if(nBytes <= 0)
                break;

            mStream.Write(buffer, 0, nBytes);
        }

    } catch {
        int code = System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.GetExceptionCode();
        Console.WriteLine("Erro Num: " + code);
        return;
    }

    buffer = mStream.ToArray();

    string data = null;
    data = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer);
    Console.WriteLine("Data is: " + data);
    Console.WriteLine("Size is: " + data.Length);
    Server.Network.ReceiveData.SelectPacket(client.Index, data);
    client.TCPClient.GetStream().Flush();
}
```

Uma boa prática é definir um protocolo para controle de fluxo, mesmo que simples. Como exemplo, podemos convencionar que antes de enviar qualquer informação, o servidor enviará 4 bytes (32 bits) indicando a quantidade de bytes que irá compor a próxima informação.

```
public static byte[] ReadBytes(System.IO.Stream stream, int size) {
    if (size <= 0)
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException();

    byte[] buffer = new byte[size];

    int i = 0;
    while (size > 0) {
        int nBytes = stream.Read(buffer, i, size);
        if (nBytes <= 0)
            break;
        i += nBytes;
        size -= nBytes;
    }

    if(size > 0) {
        byte[] nBuffer = new byte[buffer.Length - size];
        Array.Copy(buffer, 0, nBuffer, 0, nBuffer.Length);
        buffer = nBuffer;
    }

    return buffer;
}

public static void UpdateClient(UserConnection client) {
    System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream nStream = client.TCPClient.GetStream();

    byte[] buffer = null;
    try {
        int size = BitConverter.ToInt32(ReadBytes(nStream, 4), 0);
        if (size <= 0)
            throw new InvalidOperationException();

        buffer = ReadBytes(nStream, size);

        if(buffer.Length != size)
            throw new InvalidOperationException();
    } catch {
        int code = System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.GetExceptionCode();
        Console.WriteLine("Erro Num: " + code);
        return;
    }

    string data = null;
    data = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer);
    Console.WriteLine("Data is: " + data);
    Console.WriteLine("Size is: " + data.Length);
    Server.Network.ReceiveData.SelectPacket(client.Index, data);
    client.TCPClient.GetStream().Flush();
}
```

Comment: O código passado retornar o buffer como um valor nulo, poderia corrigi-lo?

Comment: O buffer retornava nulo caso ocorresse algum erro durante a leitura.  Corrigido.

Answer (score 0):

Jon Skeet solution: http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/readbinary.html

O problema com a sua solução é o Read, um stream é um fluxo e você nunca pode (pode as vezes, mas não deve) assumir que o conteúdo será sempre lido de uma vez, nem sempre o fluxo terá informações a serem consumidas, mas isso não indica que tenha terminado.

Você precisa ler até ter a certeza de ter lido tudo.

Olhando os snippets do Jon, pode-se perceber que devemos observar o resultado do Read para ter certeza que terminou. E ao terminar, verificar se o tamanho está certo. Isso quer dizer que se o Read leu 10K, não significa que ele leu tudo, a forma como você vai fazer isso depende de você, eu seguiria a linha de pensamento do Skeet.

Quando o Read retorna 0 ou negativo ele acabou, se o tamanho está errado então houve erro.

Comment: Notei que, os bytes chegam no tamanho 11076, e o data fica no tamanho 11000, o que faz sentido, já que o data falta apenas poucos caracteres. Acho que o problema pode estar relacionado ao utf8?

Comment: ALém disso, o código está escrito de forma sincrona, dessa forma, você supõe que os pacotes vão sempre chegar na ordem que foram enviados e de forma contínua, não é assim que o mundo real funciona. Um congestionamento em um dos nós da rede pode provocar retransmissão de pacotes, você precisa checar a ordem e tratar o recebimento em uma thread separada de forma assíncrona.

Comment: @user3571412, provavelmente a diferença de tamanho deve estar ocorrendo devido ao conjunto de caracteres. Tendo em vista que o padrão UTF-8 é exatamente igual ao ASCII entre os caracteres U+00..7F e que a partir de U+80 temos mais de um byte para representar um caractere, podendo se estender para até 4 bytes. Veja a tabela em: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8#Description .